# Randomly select 30% elements in a matrix using MATLAb

Tags: matlab

I need to do the following for each of elements of a matrix of size mXn:
1. flip a coin with a 0.3 probability of success.
2. if its a success set the element to zero.
3. else move to the next element.

I used the following code, but it does not give any output and produces NaN, C is the matrix of size mXn:

```
index = (rand(size(C)<=0.3));
one_index = find(index ==1);
C(one_index) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this statement

```
index = (rand(size(C)<=0.3));
```

You've messed up the parentheses so you're trying to compare if `size(C) <= 0.3`. This returns `[0 0]`, causing `rand` to create an empty matrix.

Also, the call to `find` is unnecessary.

```
C = magic(4);
index = rand(size(C)) <= 0.3;
C(index) = 0

C =

    16     2     3    13
     0    11    10     8
     9     7     6     0
     4     0    15     1
```